# How can I prevent specific groups from accessing certain Spring application context files?

Tags: spring, maven, applicationcontext

In our application, we launch certain Spring context files depending on an argument value which is specified when the application is kicked off from within the Maven command-line. I use parameter -DEnvironment=[NameOfEnv] as my field to determine which context file to use when launching the application. The code is stored in our Enterprise BitBucket/Stash.

The issue creeped up when we (Team A) were asked to share the application with another group (Team B), however, since they were offshore, much of the data in our context files were considered as "sensitive", therefore, they were unable to access/view our application context files.

Here is an illustration on what I mean:

[AppContext File Visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFi35.jpg)

I am trying to figure out how to set up Team B to have visibility to TWO CONTEXT FILES rather than all of them, as the other ones have sensitive data which they cannot see.

Here are some solutions/thoughts:

1. Create duplicate application with only their context files (quickest & dirtiest, but more headache)
2. Somehow load context files from a local location on their systems, this way, they cannot see ours
3. Load context files from a completely separate repository/project and have permissions set up accordingly. So there would be two separate 'context-related' repositories, one for Team A Context Files and the other for Team B Context Files. So in total, there would be THREE repositories, (1) Application, (2) Context Files For Team A, (3) Context Files for Team B
4. Possible encryption of context files so they cannot see the actual values?
5. Any others?

I hope this is a bit clear.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing sensitive in the context files if you use property place holders for everything.

You need to do 2 things:

1) Use different [spring profiles](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/) for each team so they have a different running app as required.

2) Use [Property Placeholders](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/) to allow for all sesnitive information to be added to property files, not directly in the context files.

You can then give team A and team B different property files and ask them to use different profiles from the same code base and same context files.

Comment: I worked on #1 these past days and am now running the application with no sensitive data in the context files! Thank you for that point. 

Regarding #2, I need to read up more on 'profiles' to determine how I would apply it in my case.

I would like to set your response as the answer, but I don't see that option around. Perhaps I don't have the points yet?